# Create single array int[] attractions in Attraction class and add createAttraction() from main class to it max of 5 to be stored otherwise full

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class Attraction {


    String description;
    private String contactDetails;
    private String guide;
    private String rating;
    private final double noTicketsSold = 0;
    private int maxGroupSize;
    private int amountActivities;
    private double ticketCost;
    private int uniqueID;
    private static int count;
    private char chosen;
    private String[] storedActivities;
    private static int id_counter = 0;
    private final int MAX_NUM_ATTRACTIONS = 5;
    private static int[] attractions;


    public Attraction(int MAX_NUM_ATTRACTIONS) {
        id_counter++;
        attractions = new int[MAX_NUM_ATTRACTIONS];
        count = 0;

    }

    public int getUniqueID() {
        return this.uniqueID;
    }



    public void recordAttraction() {

        if (count == attractions.length) {
            System.out.println("Attractions are full");
            return;
        }

        if (count < attractions.length) {

            attractions[count] =
            count++;
        }
    }


    public Attraction(char chosen, String description, double ticketCost, int maxGroupSize, String contactDetails,
                      int amountActivities, String[] storedActivities) {
        count++;
        id_counter++;
        this.chosen = chosen;
        this.description = description;
        this.ticketCost = ticketCost;
        this.maxGroupSize = maxGroupSize;
        this.contactDetails = contactDetails;
        this.amountActivities = amountActivities;
        this.storedActivities = storedActivities;
    }

    public Attraction(char chosen, String description, double ticketCost, String guide, String rating) {

        count++;
        id_counter++;
        this.chosen = chosen;
        this.description = description;
        this.ticketCost = ticketCost;
        this.guide = guide;
        this.rating = rating;

    }


    public  void displayAllDetails() {

        System.out.printf("\nID                 : %d%n", getUniqueID());
        System.out.printf("Description        : %s%n", description);
        System.out.printf("Ticket cost        : $%.2f%n", ticketCost);
        System.out.printf("Tickets sold       : %.0f%n", noTicketsSold);

        if (chosen == 'y') {

            System.out.println("Activity           :");
            int i = 0;

            while (amountActivities > i) {
                System.out.println("                   : " + storedActivities[i]);
                i++;

            }


            System.out.printf("Max Attendees      : %d%n", maxGroupSize);
            System.out.printf("Agency             : %s%n", contactDetails);


        }

        if (chosen == 'n') {

            System.out.printf("Instruction guide  : %s%n", guide);
            System.out.printf("Difficulty         : %s%n", rating);


        }
    }
}
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StageA {


    private static final Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    private Attraction attractions = null;


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        StageA a = new StageA();

        a.runMenu();

    }

    private void runMenu() {
        char selection;

        do {
            displayMenu();
            selection = sc.nextLine().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
            processSelection(selection);
        } while (selection != 'x');
    }

    private void displayMenu() {

        System.out.println("\n  **** Ozzey Attraction Menu ****");
        System.out.println("A : Add New Attraction");
        System.out.println("B : View Attraction");
        System.out.println("C : List All Attractions");
        System.out.println("D : Sell Ticket");
        System.out.println("E : Refund Ticket");
        System.out.println("F : Remove Attraction");
        System.out.println("X : Exit\n\n");
        System.out.printf("Enter selection : ");
    }


    private void createAttraction() {

        String description;
        double ticketCost;
        char chosen;
        int maxGroupSize;
        String contactDetails;
        int amountActivities;


        System.out.print("\nEnter attraction description : ");
        description = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter cost of a Ticket  : ");
        ticketCost = Double.parseDouble(sc.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Is this a supervised tour ? [Y/N] :");
        chosen = sc.nextLine().toLowerCase().charAt(0);


        switch (chosen) {


            case 'y':


                System.out.println("What is maximum permitted tour group size?");
                maxGroupSize = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());

                System.out.println("Enter the agency contact details: ");
                contactDetails = sc.nextLine();


                System.out.println("How many activity are there?");
                amountActivities = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());


                while (amountActivities < 1) {


                    System.out.println("Please enter valid number of activities great than zero");
                    System.out.println("How many activity are there?");
                    amountActivities = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());

                }


                String[] storedActivities = new String[amountActivities];
                int counter = 0;

                while (amountActivities > counter) {

                    System.out.printf("Please enter  activity #%d: ", counter);

                    storedActivities[counter] = sc.nextLine();
                    counter++;
                }

                attractions = new Attraction(chosen, description, ticketCost, maxGroupSize, contactDetails,
                        amountActivities, storedActivities);


                break;

            case 'n':

                String guide;
                String rating;


                System.out.printf("Enter the instruction guide:\n");
                guide = sc.nextLine();
                System.out.printf("Enter the difficulty rating:\n");
                rating = sc.nextLine();
                attractions = new Attraction(chosen, description, ticketCost, guide, rating);
                break;

            default:
                System.out.print("Please Enter valid answer ");
                System.out.println("Is this a supervised tour ? [Y/N] :");

        }


    }


    private void processSelection(char selection) {

        switch (selection) {
            case 'a':
                attractions.recordAttraction();
                createAttraction();
                break;
            case 'b':

                System.out.printf("b");
                break;

            case 'c':
                System.out.printf("c");
                break;

            case 'd':
                System.out.printf("d");
                break;
            case 'e':
                System.out.printf("e");
                break;
            case 'f':
                System.out.printf("f");
                break;
            case 'x':
                System.out.println("Good Bye!");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid input, try again\n");


        }
    }
```

Hi all i stuck a part of my project for school i have to create a single array in my Attraction class called  `int[] attractions` that can have a max of 5  stored `createAttraction()` from my stageA class.
When they choose 'a' in my switch statement this were i add `createAttraction();` when user has created five attraction in will then tell the user its full and no more can be added. i tried a couple of things but i stuck any help wont be appreciated.

Note: this is the way project has to be setup.

Comment: you need to initialize attractions , it's value is null in StageA class

Answer (score 0):

Here are few things you should change in your code :

1. Change the constructor in attractions class, since you have already set  final variable as 5 and if it is fixed, you do not need constructor with parameter: MAX_NUM_ATTRACTIONS
2. You need to initialise attraction object in  StageA  class :

   private Attraction attractions = null;  => private Attraction attractions = new Attraction()
3. Decide when you want to increment counter variable, when you dorecordAttraction or actually creating one and count should be checked greater or equal to attractions length/ MAX_NUM_ATTRACTIONS
4. return a value from method record Attraction to decide if you have to proceed with createAttraction or not

Comment: thank you Sai Patil  took two minutes to fix.

Comment: you are welcome @KevinBrown. Please mark it as answer, if it fixed your issue